# laravel 5.2 транзакции

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Пытаюсь создать строки в бд (Inno db)

```
DB::beginTransaction();
Company::create($request->all());
```

Запись создается вне зависимости от того, вызываю ли я `DB::commit()` или нет.

`DB::rollBack()` не работает. Почему такое поведение?

```
public function store(CreateCompanyRequest $request)
{

    DB::beginTransaction();
    Company::create($request->all());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверь еще раз точно какую версию DB ты используешь возможно у тебя там все же MyISAM стоит ? А еще попробуй использовать замыкание и вызови исключение, и посмотри на поведение, что произойдет.

в случае замыкания будет выглядеть так

```
DB::transaction(function()
{

    $company = Company::create([]);

    if( !$company )
    {
        throw new \Exception('Company not created');
    }
});
```

И попробуй обновиться до последней версии 5.2 именно, судя по bug трекеру, там проблем особо ни у кого не возникало с этим.